# retrieving picture from database and show it for a time

Tags: javascript, php

im a newbie in javascript, so basically i want to retrieve picture from database. Once the picture is retrieved, it will be on the screen for 10 min and after 10 min, the picture will disappear. any suggestion what code should it be?

Comment: This question shows little attempt to solve the problem yourself, that is why it is getting down votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img id="img_id" src="your image path retrieved from DB">

<script type="text/javascript">

setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('img_id').style.display = 'none';
},2000);

</script>
```

[try this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MxWUs/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery effects to make the image appear and disappear see [here] (http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)